# Import XSD Schema file in another XSD Schema file in mule esb...,

Tags: mule, schema, xsd-validation

I need to import XSD Schema file in another XSD Schema file, I have tried like

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/types" schemaLocation="C:/Users/AnypointStudio/PriojectName/src/test/resources/datatypes.xsd"/> 

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/types" schemaLocation="./datatypes.xsd"/> 

<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/types" schemaLocation=".//datatypes.xsd"/>
```

but getting following error message: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'C:\Users\AnypointStudio\src\test\resources\datatypes.xsd', 
 because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Please suggest me on this..,

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/types" schemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/AnypointStudio/PriojectName/src/test/resources/datatypes.xsd" />
```